# Range Pattern using for loop

Tags: scala, apache-spark, for-loop, pattern-matching

I want to find range for input using scala as given below input dataframe

```
Input
    scala> val r_df = Seq((1,"1 to 6"),(2,"44/1 to 3")).toDF("id","range")
    r_df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [id: int, range: string]


scala> r_df.show
+---+---------+
| id|    range|
+---+---------+
|  1|   1 to 6|
|  2|44/1 to 3|
+---+---------+
```

for loop udf

```
val survey_to1 = udf((data1: Int, data2: Int) => {
      val arr = new ArrayBuffer[Int]()
      for(i <- data1 to data2)
      {
        arr+= i
      }
      arr
    })




r_df4.withColumn("new", survey_to1(col("new1"),col("new3"))).show(false)
```

applied above for loop udf to dataframe, it is taking only "1 to 6"

```
+---+---------+----+----+----+------------------+
|id |range    |new1|new2|new3|new               |
+---+---------+----+----+----+------------------+
|1  |1 to 6   |1   |to  |6   |[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]|
|2  |44/1 to 3|44/1|to  |3   |null              |
+---+---------+----+----+----+------------------+
```

Expected output

```
+---+---------+----+----+----+------------------+
|id |range    |new1|new2|new3|new               |
+---+---------+----+----+----+------------------+
|1  |1 to 6   |1   |to  |6   |[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]|
|2  |44/1 to 3|44/1|to  |3   |[44/1,44/2,44,3]  |
+---+---------+----+----+----+------------------+
```

Comment: do you think 44/1 is Int type when it calls the udf?

Answer (score 0):

With those specific string patterns:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.udf

val patern = "([0-9.]{2}/[0-9.]{1}|[0-9.]{1}) to ([0-9.]{1})".r

def createArray = udf { str : String =>
    val patern(from, _to) = str
    ((from.split("/").last.toInt to _to.toInt).toArray)
      .map(el => {
        val strPattern = from.split("/")
        s"""${ if(strPattern.length > 1) strPattern(0) + "/" + el else el
        }"""
      })
  }

val r_df = Seq((1,"1 to 6"),(2,"44/1 to 3")).toDF("id","range")
r_df.withColumn("array", createArray($"range")).show(false)
```

gives:

```
+---+---------+------------------+
|id |range    |array             |
+---+---------+------------------+
|1  |1 to 6   |[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]|
|2  |44/1 to 3|[44/1, 44/2, 44/3]|
+---+---------+------------------+
```

to add a patter to support strings with the format "3a to 5a" just update the regex with:

```
val patern = "([0-9.]{2}/[0-9.]{1}|[0-9.]{1})[a-zA-Z0-9_]* to ([0-9.]{1})[a-zA-Z0-9_]*".r
```

For example:

```
+---+---------+------------------+
|id |range    |array             |
+---+---------+------------------+
|1  |1 to 6   |[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]|
|2  |44/1 to 3|[44/1, 44/2, 44/3]|
|3  |3a to 5a |[3, 4, 5]         |
+---+---------+------------------+
```

Comment: How about characters like "a to c","1/a to 1/c","3a to 5a".ouput "a,b,c","1/a,1/b,1/c","3a,4a,5a"

Comment: You will need to improve the regex with all the patterns that you need

Comment: I did that adding pattern in Patern, but getting error as string.It is taking only integer values

Comment: Can you add the example that you are testing?

Comment: val createArray = udf { str : String =>
      val patern1(from, _to) = str
      from.split("").toString.toArray
      _to.split("").toString.toArray
        .map(el => {
          val strPattern = from.split("")
          val strPattern1 = _to.split("")
          val strpattern3 = strPattern.union(strPattern1)
          s"${
            if (strpattern3.length > 1) strpattern3(0) + "" + el else el
          }"
        })
    }

Comment: the above is the testing

Comment: please, update your question with the changes. I need the string that you are testing to change the regex.

Comment: the string is "3a to 5a"